# Internal SQL Server error when i run the delete query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Whenever I try to run this delete query:

```
delete from [Production].[dbo].[Package] 
where [iVersionID] = 3258
```

I get the error message:

> 21 row(s) affected
>   Msg 8624, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Author_Delete, Line 55
>   Internal SQL Server error

I am not if it a server issue or it is the query that is not working, as I tried delete query in other table and it was working ok.

Comment: That error is `Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor could not produce a query plan. For more information, contact Customer Support Services.`  is there a trigger on the table? Looks like the delete itself succeeded from the "21 row(s) affected"

Comment: Can you share the full stored procedure.

Comment: Can you check if there is a trigger on record deletetion on that table? And also that specific stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

I know this was a long time ago, but for anyone coming across this problem again I had the same issue today and it was fixed simply by changing a couple SET operators at the start of the sp.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
go
```

Comment: Hmm, someone else said this in a deleted answer to this Q. What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: That is a very good question - the table that was causing me problems had no filtered indices or indexed views or computed columns that would normally cause issues with these set operators so to be honest I was struggling to understand why also.